# Rails: Access image from assets/images from public/ folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access images from app/assets/images/ 
from public/404.html in rails

I was able to render the image from local using 
`background-image: url("/assets/404-error.jpg")`;

But the same image wont render in deployment

Is there a way to render the image instead of adding it in the public/ directory?

Comment: `Won't work` is not enough information. What specifically goes wrong in the production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Sprockets to compile the assets on production (Rails default):

```
background-image: asset-url('404-error.jpg');
```

From [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass):

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.
>
> ```
> asset-url("rails.png") returns url(/assets/rails.png)
> asset-path("rails.png") returns "/assets/rails.png"
> ```